Reverse rollover IRA and rule of 55
I'm looking to retire after 55+.  Due to job changes through the years, I've rolled over previous 401K's to a traditional IRA.  I want to avoid early withdrawal penalties and take advantage of the "Rule of 55".  Can I reverse rollover the traditional IRA back to my current 401k prior to retirement and avoid the IRA penalties?

Do you not expect your current 401(K) to last 4 years until you tune 59 1/2?

Correct.  For when 401K is too new or low in balance.

It is allowed (see the rollover chart here), but at the discretion of the plan whether to accept such rollovers. You'll need to reach out to the plan administrator and confirm with them if you can.
